# Layout messes up when zooming in

Tags: layout, navbar, responsive, zooming

I'm working on a responsive website and the layout messes up when zooming in.
The elements that get really messy are the header and navabar and the footer, while the content of some pages actually scales as it should.
How can I fix this?`

Answer (score 0):

You could try using bootstrap, which is useful in making webpages look good with zooming. You can get it here:

http://getbootstrap.com/

Comment: Hey there, thanks a lot for your answer. I was actually trying to avoid bootstrap as need more freedom on the layout front.